# R: subset a data frame condition on sum of the subset data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame manipulation question.

I would like to find the subset of data frame "data1" which sum of each col equal to another data frame "data2".

Here is my code:

```
AA<-c(2,3,1,4,9)
BB<-c(5,13,9,1,2)

A1<-c(5)
B1<-c(18)

data1<-data.frame(AA,BB)
data2<-data.frame(A1,B1)

library(dplyr)
subset(data1, ((sum(AA) ==data2$A1 )  &&  (sum(BB) ==data2$B1 ) ) )
```

I am wondering if any other algorithm would help?

Thanks!

Comment: Since you are using `numeric`, your assumption that `%in%` will work is very fragile, see [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f).

Comment: Do I understand this right? For each row in `data2`, you want all combinations of rows from `data1` where the column-sums are equal to the row. If so, how much data do you actually have? Any algorithm would scale badly, requiring significant conditioning and such to mitigate the combinatorial inefficiency. (BTW: do not include images of data, just reusable code please!)

Comment: Thanks @r2evans for pointing me to check the `%in%`. The link is very helpful and I appreciate you. I understand this questions will cause inefficiency when coding the algorithm. I brought up this questions because I would like to code a situation of merging two table without a unique key but based on known ties between two tables. For the data size, I have 2 rows in "data2". I understand it will cause inefficiency for any algorithm.

Comment: It's not about inefficiency so much as surprises or fragility as r2e said. For example, `x = .1 + .2; x %in% .3` ...

Comment: Thanks @Frank for your example. It makes sense for me now.

Comment: My comment about inefficiency was targeting the combinatorial explosion that looking for all combinations of rows will grow towards. It is exponential. "Simple solutions" will be grossly inefficient, "less-inefficient" algorithms will be relatively complex. Thanks for the concrete example, @Frank.

Comment: I see. Thanks for explaining and pointing out my mistakes. It makes sense for me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution only considers the scenario that you want to calculate the sum from any two rows. If you want to test other row numbers, you will need to create those combinations by changing the numbers in the `combn` function. `final_data` is the final output. If there are multiple matches, you may want to keep the `final_data` as a list.

```
# Prepare example datasets
AA<-c(2,3,1,4,9)
BB<-c(5,13,9,1,2)

A1<-c(5)
B1<-c(18)

data1<-data.frame(AA,BB)
data2<-data.frame(A1,B1)

# Load packages
library(tidyverse)

# Use combn to find out all the combination of row number
row_indices <- as.data.frame(t(combn(1:nrow(data1), 2)))

# Prepare a list of data frame. Each data frame is one row from row_indices
row_list <- row_indices %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  split(f = .$rowid)

# Based on row_list to subset data1
sub_list <- map(row_list, function(dt){
  temp_data <- data1 %>% filter(row_number() %in% c(dt$V1, dt$V2))
  return(temp_data)
})

# Calcualte the sum of each data frame in sub_list
sub_list2 <- map(sub_list, function(dt){
  dt2 <- dt %>% 
    summarise_all(funs(sum(.))) %>%
    setNames(c("A1", "B1"))
  return(dt2)
})

# Compare each data frame in sub_list2 with data2
# Find the one that is the same and store the logical results in result_indices
result_indices <- map_lgl(sub_list2, function(dt) setequal(dt, data2))

# Get the final output
final_data <- sub_list[result_indices][[1]]

final_data
  AA BB
1  2  5
2  3 13
```

Comment: Wow! This is exactly what I need. Thank you so much! I appreciate your help.